# Regularization of a divergent series versus the asymptotic behavior of its partial sums?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, asymptotics, divergent-series

I was wondering if the asymptotic behavior of a divergent series' partial sums had anything to do with the regularized divergent series.  For example, how does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sqrt{1+n^2}$ compare to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n$, where we apply any method of regularization to both series?  I note that zeta regularization is easy to do in the second, but not in the first, for example, but as for the partial sums, they are asymptotic:

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\cfrac{\sum_{n=1}^N\sqrt{1+n^2}}{\sum_{n=1}^Nn}=1$$

---

I'd like to use the above as an example, but I'd still like answers to talk more generally about the relationships of regularization and asymptotic behavior of partial sums.